# How to navigate through MudTabPanels when clicking a button?

Tags: c#, mudblazor

When the user clicks on a button, it must go to a specific tab of my MudTabPanel, is that possible?

```
<MudTabs Elevation="0" Rounded="true" Centered="true">
    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab1" ID="1" tabindex="1" @bind-ActivePanelIndex="activeIndex">
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab2" ID="2" tabindex="2" @bind-ActivePanelIndex="activeIndex">
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab3" ID="3" tabindex="3" @bind-ActivePanelIndex="activeIndex">
    </MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>
<MudButton OnClick="@(()=>GoToTab())">Go To Tab 3</MudButton>

@code {
    public int activeIndex { get; set; } = 1;

    public async Task GoToTab()
    {
        activeIndex = 3;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the `ActivePanelIndex` property **for** `MudTabs` [docs](https://mudblazor.com/api/tabs#properties:%7E:text=The%20current%20active%20panel%20index.%20Also%20with%20Bidirectional%20Binding)

*Note* The index starts starts at 0

```
<MudTabs Elevation="0" Rounded="true" Centered="true" @bind-ActivePanelIndex="@_activePanel">
    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab1" ID="1" tabindex="1" >
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab2" ID="2" tabindex="2" >
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab3" ID="3" tabindex="3" >
    </MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>

<MudButton OnClick="@(()=>GoToTab(2))">Go To Tab 3</MudButton>


@code{
    int _activePanel;
    void GoToTab(int tabIndex){
        _activePanel = tabIndex;
    }
}
```

[MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cawdksRPkbMuqdlI)